# Regex Matching a Naming Convention

Tags: regex, vba, file-system, file-structure

**Program Purpose**

So, I have a naming convention for certain folders.

I want to take in a folder name, and determine if it conforms to the convention.

---

**Naming Convention**

The convention (case insensitive) can be as simple as

> "Surname, Firstname"

It could be as complicated as

> "Surname (meta), Firstname (meta) & Firstname (meta) ; Surname (meta),
>   Firstname (meta) & Firstname (meta)"

---

It is broken down like so:

- A name is made up of a `[Surname]` and 1 or 2 `[Firstnames]`.
- Each `[Surname]` and `[Firstname]` can have an optional `[ (metadata)]`
  after it.
- If there are 2 `[Firstnames]`, they are separated by  `[ & ]`.
- A name can, optionally, have a second set of `[Surname]` &
  `[Firstnames]`. Separated from the first set by `[ ; ]`.

---

As part of a [larger program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136192/validating-filesystem-structure), I have a class object which handles information relating to a folder.

When a folder name is passed to the class, it validates the naming convention. It currently does this via regex but I find regex to be an incredible source of bugs and un-maintainable code.

So, is there a better way?

---

**Program Flow**

1. Receive folder name
2. Copy folder name
3. Regex Match/Replace the copy with `vbNullString`
4. If the copy is now `vbNullString`, the whole string matched and is valid

---

**Validation Code**

```
Private Sub AddNamesFromClientFolder(ByVal ClientFolderName As String)
    '/ Copy folder name
    '/ Replace copy's regex matching with null string
    '/ If the copy is now a null string, the whole name matched and is valid

    '/ Client Folder names should be of the form:
    '/ "[Surname] ( [misc] ), [Firstname] ( [Misc] ) & [Firstname] ( [Misc] ) ; [Other Surname] ( [Misc] ), [Other Firstname] ( [Misc] ) & [Other Firstname] ( [Misc] )"
    '/
    '/ With minimum form:
    '/ "[Surname], [Firstname]"

    Dim IsValid As Boolean
    If Len(ClientFolderName) > 0 Then

        Dim validationRegex As RegExp
        Set validationRegex = New RegExp
        With validationRegex
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = ClientFolderValidationRegex
        End With

        Dim testString As String
        testString = ClientFolderName
        testString = validationRegex.Replace(testString, vbNullString)
        IsValid = (testString = vbNullString)

        this.IsValid = IsValid

    Else

        this.IsValid = False

    End If

End Sub
```

---

**Building the regex pattern**

```
Public Function ClientFolderValidationRegex() As String
    '/ CG = "Capture Group"

    Const L_CASE_LETTERS As String = "a-z"
    Const U_CASE_LETTERS As String = "A-Z"
    Const ALL_NUMBERS As String = "0-9"
    Const NAME_PUNCTUATION As String = "`'!@\-_"
    Const ALL_ALLOWED_PUNCTUATION As String = "`!""£$%^&*\-_+=\[\]{}:;@'~#<,>.?\/\\ "

    Dim delim As String

    '/ captures a single, contiguous group of letters/numbers/limited name punctuation e.g. "O'Malley"
    Dim nameCG As String
    nameCG = "([" & L_CASE_LETTERS & U_CASE_LETTERS & ALL_NUMBERS & NAME_PUNCTUATION & "]+)"

    '/ captures the following: " (anything you want in here)"
    Dim bracketedCG As String
    bracketedCG = "( \(" & "([" & L_CASE_LETTERS & U_CASE_LETTERS & ALL_NUMBERS & ALL_ALLOWED_PUNCTUATION & "]+)" & "\))"

    '/ Captures the following: "name (anything you want)" where " (anything you want)" may or may not be present
    Dim nameSectionCG As String
    nameSectionCG = "(" & nameCG & bracketedCG & "?" & ")"

    '/ Surname portion of a filename should be the same as standard name section
    Dim surnameCG As String
    surnameCG = nameSectionCG

    '/ Firstname portion might have an optional " & [name section]"
    delim = " & "
    Dim firstnameCG As String
    firstnameCG = "(" & nameSectionCG & "(" & delim & nameSectionCG & ")?" & ")"

    '/ Full name section of a filename is "[surname section], [firstname section]"
    delim = ", "
    Dim fullNamesCG As String
    fullNamesCG = "(" & surnameCG & delim & firstnameCG & ")"

    '/ Full filename might optionally have another " ; [full name section]"
    delim = " ; "
    Dim fullFilenameCG As String
    fullFilenameCG = "(" & fullNamesCG & "(" & delim & fullNamesCG & ")?" & ")"

    ClientFolderValidationRegex = fullFilenameCG

End Function
```

---

[Link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qS2bH3/1)

**Regex Matching Examples:**

**Match:**

> Lannister, Tyrion
>
> Lannister, Cersei (& Joffrey, Myrcella, Tommen {All Deceased})
>
> Stark, Eddard (Ned, Deceased) ; Tully, Catelyn (Also Deceased)

**No Match:**

> Tyrion Lannister
>
> Lannister, Queen Cersei
>
> Stark, Ned RED WEDDING

Comment: Can you post a set of example filenames that illustrate your pattern, examples both positive (matching) and negative (close but no cigar)?

Comment: Related: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Don't have time to turn it into an answer, but if you're looking for an alternative to Regex, you could consider writing a state machine yourself. It's a common way of doing custom processing of strings (in fact regex expressions compile down to state machines anyway).

Comment: So `van Houten, Milhouse`and `Gödel, Kurt` should not match?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please, don't blame me, blame the business logic. For better or worse, my entire **industry** operates on the assumption that people have one surname and one firstname and that both can be written using the standard english alphabet.

Comment: @Zak: Is moving the folders away from using natural keys and over to, say, UUID/GUID an option? Then storing the name either in a database or a loose file inside the folder? Also, that's not for better or worse. It's just for the worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using regex for this? It makes no sense to match complicated naming conventions with something as low-level as Regular Expressions.

You either have to go higher in your abstraction by using a proper Grammar (which is basically what your separated groups do, but better) or go **lower** to forego the semantics you impose here.

Consider the following pseudo-ish code:

```
Dim isValid As Boolean
Dim Names(2) As String
isValid = True 
Names = ClientFolderName.Split(" ; ")
For Each Name As String In Names
    isValid = isValid And IsValidName(Name)
Next
```

This drops the first barrier that's overcomplicating your regex: the fact that it may contain two things.

Since you're only interested in validity you can use the following Function to check the validity of it's sub-parts

```
Function IsValidName(Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim NameParts(2) As String
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = True
    NameParts = Name.Split(", ")
    result = result And IsValidSurname(NameParts(1))
    result = result And IsValidFirstname(NameParts(2))
    IsValidName = result
End Function
```

`IsValidSurname` and `IsValidFirstname` are **significantly easier** to implement and understand with regex than trying to instantly validate the whole thing with Regex. In addition to being much more maintainable you also get to have separate responsibilities as a bonus.

Follow great advice from someone who's come ages before us:

> Divide and Conquer

This technique does not only apply in military, it's also a **hugely** useful and important skill during software development.

Answer (score 7):

Have you ever heard about [tussenvoegsels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussenvoegsel)? They're parts of people's names. Well, in the Netherlands anyway. When used for authors, it's usually done as "van Surname, FirstName". Your regex doesn't support this, instead only accepting the last word of the surname. You should allow surnames to consist of multiple words.

---

```
Dim IsValid As Boolean
If Len(ClientFolderName) > 0 Then

    Dim validationRegex As RegExp
    Set validationRegex = New RegExp
    With validationRegex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = ClientFolderValidationRegex
    End With

    Dim testString As String
    testString = ClientFolderName
    testString = validationRegex.Replace(testString, vbNullString)
    IsValid = (testString = vbNullString)

    this.IsValid = IsValid

Else

    this.IsValid = False

End If
```

What's the purpose of `IsValid` here, if you're just going to nearly-directly write to `this.IsValid` anyway? Why not do it like this?

```
If Len(ClientFolderName) > 0 Then

    Dim validationRegex As RegExp
    Set validationRegex = New RegExp
    With validationRegex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = ClientFolderValidationRegex
    End With

    Dim testString As String
    testString = ClientFolderName
    testString = validationRegex.Replace(testString, vbNullString)

    this.IsValid = (testString = vbNullString)

Else

    this.IsValid = False

End If
```

Comment: I have one of those last names (but not with "van") and this is a huge problem for so many systems. That includes some really important systems, like the one at the DMV (and now the last name on my driver's licence does not match the one on my birth certificate).